# how to hide or completely remove address bar of child winodow using window.open()

Tags: window.open, address-bar

I want to **hide/remove address bar** of a child document which is opened using
`window.open();`.

### JavaScript

```js
newwin = window.open('child.html',
 'newwin',
 'width =     900,
 height =     750,
 toolbar =    no,
 scrollbars = no,
 location =   0,
 resizable =  no
');
```

this code actually **disables the address bar**, but **does not hide it**.

I don't want to show address bar to end users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it's a security precaution.

The only place this is possible is if you're using Internet Explorer and the site is added to trusted sites list.

You may want to consider other options like [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)